How to speed up querying records on a timestamp without time zone column?
Let's suppose as a result of a LEFT JOIN I end up with a Films table for example:



id
title
begins
ends




1
The Lord Of The Rings
2024-04-25 17:46:00
2024-04-25 20:46:00


2
The Matrix
2024-06-05 11:46:00
2024-06-05 13:46:00



Where both begins and ends are of the type timestamp without timezone.
I want to get records with the following priority:

Films that are currently running
Films that will run from now until specified endTime
Films that have ran in the past 3 days

I can do something like:
SELECT * from FILMS WHERE begins >= Now()::timestamp - INTERVAL '3 days' AND ends < endTime::timestamp 
ORDER BY 
   CASE 
      WHEN endTime::timestamp > Now()::timestamp AND starts < Now()::timestamp THEN 1
      WHEN starts < Now()::timestamp THEN 2
      ELSE 3
   END;
LIMIT lim;


Is there a way to use indexes to make this faster?


Is there a way to use indexes to make this faster?

create index on films (begins,ends) include (id,title);

And once you analyze your table, this:
explain analyze verbose
SELECT * from FILMS
WHERE begins >= Now()::timestamp - INTERVAL '3 days' 
  AND ends < now()+'5 hours'::interval
ORDER BY 
   CASE 
      WHEN now()+'5 hours'::interval > Now()::timestamp 
      AND begins < Now()::timestamp THEN 1
      WHEN begins < Now()::timestamp THEN 2
      ELSE 3
   END
LIMIT 500;

Goes down from Execution Time: 1087.371 ms to 47.981 ms which you can test in this demo on 700k random movies over the last 60 days. That's a covering index enabling index-only scans.
